# Error Code 11004: Host not found from Firefox (but works on IE7 and Chrome)

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, firefox

I have a custom localhost, let´s say beta_localhost. The DNS is configured and I can access it without problem from Chrome and from IE7.

It get this error from Firefox:

- Error Code 11004: Host not found
- Background: This error indicates that the gateway could not find the IP address of the website you are trying to access, possibly due to lack of information in the DNS server.
- Server: servername
- Source: DNS error

I guess we have an IIS behind to manage the DNS.

Because I´m getting the error only on firefox but not on other browsers I guess is browser specific. Maybe I could bypass the problem with some option on about:config?

Comment: Don't use underscores in domain names. They aren't valid.

Comment: Wow, didn´t know, I guess that maybe Firefox is more strict on that and that´s why it don´t allow it? Thanks for your help, I´ll try to confirm that changing this solve the problem.